# css inline-blocks and bootstrap grid system output

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to have a specific `HTML` markup of my divs using `css` and `bootstrap 3.2`. The image below demonstrates the result I want to get.

I've used the bootstrap grid system so that my page would be responsive and properly displayed in small screen devices. This is the code I've tried.  And I used http://www.bootply.com to test it.

Any ideas how to get the markup ?

```
<div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid gray; width:150px; height:150px;">
    <img src='' alt="image go here !"/>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid" style="display:inline-block;">
    <div class="row" style="border:1px solid gray;">
      <div class="col-md-9">This is the product name</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 text-right">1 230.99</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid gray;">
      <div class="col-md-6">Property 1</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">Property 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The desired result :**
[image: The desired result]

**EDIT : The result I get :**
[image: The result I get]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[I've created a Bootply for you.](http://www.bootply.com/Vrv30ejxyT)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              This is the product name
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              1 230.99
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              Property 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              Property 2
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the space between the image and the other content is too big, that's why I didn't include the image in the bootstrap grid system.

Comment: Do you still find it to big after change `.col-md-3` to `.col-md-2`? [See my updated Bootly](http://www.bootply.com/a8vgNCTxmZ). If so, let me know. We'll add some CSS.

Comment: By fixing the width of the div cotaining the image to 185px, i've the markup wanted. Thank you.