# Bootstrap grid system col of two high

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How would one achieve the setup shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlIwn.png) using the Bootstrap grid system? The green rectangles represent Bootstrap panels and the orange rectangle represents a Bootstrap Jumbotron.

(Don't bother the text in the image)

This is the code I have at the moment (the %%%CONTENT%%% are being replaced with PHP so don't bother them):

```
    <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:rgba(231,231,231,0.5);">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>%%%JUMBOTRON%%%</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">%%%TITEL%%%</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    %%%CONTENT%%%
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">%%%TITEL%%%</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            %%%CONTENT%%%
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">%%%TITEL%%%</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            %%%CONTENT%%%
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">%%%TITEL%%%</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            %%%CONTENT%%%
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">%%%TITEL%%%</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            %%%CONTENT%%%
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried searching it but I don't really know how to properly word it. I tried the code of this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441642/css-inline-blocks-and-bootstrap-grid-system-output?rq=1)

Comment: Okay, I updated the quetion with the code I have at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your structure should be:
-Nav
-Jumbotron
-Row separated in 2 halfs
-The second half contains 2 rows of full width

something simmilar to this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <!-- ... rest of your nav configuration -->
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Jumbo!</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
           left side
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                   right side 1
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                   right side 2
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Panels as described in the original question:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:rgba(231,231,231,0.5);">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>%%%JUMBOTRON%%%</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6"><!--Column Left-->
      <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">%%%TITLE%%%</div>
          <div class="panel-body">%%%CONTENT%%%<br/>Note: The height of this panel is independent of the others<br/>You could set the height using CSS if needed.</div>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div><!--End Column Left-->

    <div class="col-md-6"><!--Column Right-->
      <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">%%%TITLE%%%</div>
          <div class="panel-body">%%%CONTENT%%%</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">%%%TITLE%%%</div>
          <div class="panel-body">%%%CONTENT%%%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--End Column Right-->  
  </div><!--End Container-->
</div><!--End Row-->
```